# $addField query does not work as expected

Tags: mongodb

I am running this query to add new field in my document, and it run successfully but does not update the document in mongodb.(movies is the collection name, mongodb version - 4.2.15 Community)

```
db.movies.aggregate([{
 $addFields: {
   totalHomework: "123312" ,
   totalQuiz: "12312"
 }}])
```

Comment: $addFields isn't supposed to update the document in the database.  Try using `update` instead of `aggregate`

Comment: $set is actually just an alias for $addFields.  The name $addFields doesn't fully reflect that you can modify existing fields rather than just adding new fields. What does this mean?.

Comment: Check here  https://www.practical-mongodb-aggregations.com/guides/project.html

Answer (score 0):

update

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    totalHomework: "123312",
    totalQuiz: "12312"
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6d8dr18YBMc)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I am trying to add new field in my mongo document. Thats when i came across $addField.